# Computing a large mixed equation in java

Tags: java, math, expression-evaluation

Say I'm given an expression like

**(1/2) + (3/4) + (5/8) + (2/10) + (3/2) + (10/1)**

How might I go about computing this expression as a **float** value in such a way that if the expression where to change I could still compute it?

I initially thought I could parse it from a string but ran into big problems. I then shifted to manually cutting the values into two arrays - Denominators and numerators but I felt that that was cheating the spirit of the exercise a bit. It also wouldn't allow flexibility in terms of the values presented.

Can this be done without 3rd party libraries and the like?

Comment: "that if the expression where to change I could still compute it?"... can you please explain this more clearly

Comment: I mean to say: If I where handed a similar expression to compute, would I be able to use the same method or class to compute it.

Comment: "Can this be done without 3rd party libraries and the like?"  - Simple answer.  Yes.  Read the linked questions.  (Evaluating the parsed expression tree is easy ...)

Comment: Re: "I initially thought I could parse it from a string but ran into big problems": You should delete this question, and instead, ask questions about those problems. Because yes, you should be able to parse it from a string.